# Inline alignment title in circular custom button

Tags: android, android-layout, button, floating-action-button

I created a simple circular button to create - and + buttons for a custom dialog picker.

[image]

As seen in the screenshot the `-` and the `+` are shifted a little bit down and not centered in the middle of the custom background.

My custom background in the `drawable/circular_button.xml` looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <size android:width="30sp" android:height="30sp"/>

</shape>
```

The button is configured like this inside the `LinearLayout`

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decrease_one"
            android:layout_width="40sp"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

In one of the posts I read about the tag `minHeight` but it didn't solve my problem.Any ideas ?

Comment: batter to use FlaotingActionButton

Comment: it brings you a more benefits rather to you create a custom  button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batter to use FloatingActionButton mini

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/activity_my_digital_executor_fabDigitalex"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:fabSize="mini"
    card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_new_plus" />
```

Add `'com.android.support:design:26.0.+'` in your App dependencies

Answer (score 0):

This is happen because of your Button's android:textSize="30sp" if you set 50sp its goes down the line more, 
Just convert your Buttons to Textviews and set android:gravity="center" also keep your textsize 30sp

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/decrease_2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:text="+"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: that should work  but then you lose the "higlighting" effect on tapping.

Answer (score -1):

If you are use a Imageview instead of Textview than your problem is solved.